# Magento Migration- extensions

Tags: magento2, extensions

I have magento 1 and a message popped  to change to magento 2. I purchased two extensions for the old platform now i have to purchase them again for the 2 version?

Answer (score 1):

while the code migration script is available:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/bk-migration-guide.html#migrate-extensions-code

but I think that for the sake of your business you should buy the same extensions for Magento 2.

Development and maintenance costs will be even much more. Count yourself - proper working shop is more important, the final profit will cover all purchases of updates.